# Simple Form button submit doesn't show in IE 8-7

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer

Those super IE troubleshooters out there. Here is the bug. At the bottom of this form: http://xquives.kiaistudio.com/new-form/index.php there are two buttons. They appear perfect in IE10 FF etc., but not in IE 9-8-7. How do I fix this?

buttonbox css:

```
#buttonbox {
    display : block;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom : 20px;
    overflow:auto;
    float:right;
}
```

button class css:

```
.button {
    background:#5f6156;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color:#FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:10px;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
}
.button:hover {
    color:#D3411F;
}
```

button div html:

```
<div id="buttonbox">
    <input name="SOUMETTRE" type="submit" class="button"/>
    <input name="REINITIALISER" type="reset" class="button" />
</div>
```

--
more info, the button in IE 7-8-9 that are useless are black with no text (or black text) so we dont see the writing... but trigger the post from OK .... just cannot see the text that IS there in FF or IE10

--

Here is a multiple screen capture to SUM it up !

[image]

Comment: Please post the code here so if that link goes away this question isn't useless to others in the future.

Comment: Please describe issue in more detail, including what the button currently looks like in IE, and what the button should look like.

Comment: The input tag needs to have a `value` attribute to tell the browser what text to display

Comment: How can something so simple can be the problem. And one of the thing that "got" me is that i validate. How can i validate without something so absolutely important as the text... Cody, your the best... submit your comment as answer and it will be accepted right away !

Comment: @menardmam Ok! I never saw your comment. But I will post it as an answer as soon as I get on my computer. I will also link to a few articles to help explain a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input tag needs to have a value attribute to tell the browser what text to display – Cody Guldner Mar 22 at 20:34

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't see all of the code because the link is broken, I would assume that you have inserted the text into the `input` by some sort of pseudo-class, such as `:before` or `:after`. I know this, because

1. You don't have a `value` attribute on your `input`
2. You must be using something that isn't supported in lower browsers
3. So it probably isn't jQuery, because that has good browser support

So to solve this, all you need to do is add a `value` to the `input`. This will assure that the text is always displayed, because it is hard-coded into the HTML.

The buttons will still have their functionality. Its just that nobody will know what they do/